# Jquery serialize and passing in other custom post data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

```
function DoAjax( args )
{
    var formData = "?" + $("form[name=" + args.formName + "]").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: args.url + formData,
        data: {
            request: args.request
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            args.callback.html(data);
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            alert("error: " + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ".");
        }
    });

    return false;       
}
```

I need to pass in a custom bit of data to my php script called "request" which will denote which process to run on the php page... but I also want to serialize any other form fields on my form. Is this the correct way of doing it (add the serialize to the end of the URL) because I just cannot seem to get anything from my PHP $_POST["whatever"]

EDIT:::///

```
<?php                                 
    $request = $_POST[ "request" ];   

    if( isset( $request ) )
    {
        require_once( "includes.php" );

        function LogInWithClientCred()
        {
            $username = CheckIsset( "username" );
            $password = CheckIsset( "password" );

            echo $_REQUEST["username"];
            echo $_GET["username"]; // echos correctly the username.. but I want it to be post data instead!
```

Please ignore the security awesomeness, it is pseudo for your purpose.

Comment: Currently, your form variables will be available under `$_GET`, if you want them under post, you'll need to use `$.param` on your `{request:args.request}` and add your form data to it, then pass `formData` to the `data:` option.

Comment: $.param, i'll look it up, thanks.

Comment: This is the correct way, but all your form data will be passed into `GET` and your `args.request` will be `POST`

Comment: @JamesT `$.param` will take your object and generate `request=somevalue`

Comment: args.request is only a single string... let me show the PHP part that might help.

Comment: James try $_REQUEST["whatever"] or see my answer below where $_POST[formData] should give you serialized form data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine `formData` and your additional data into one string.

```
var formData =  $("form[name=" + args.formName + "]").serialize() + "&request=" + args.request;

$.ajax({
    url: args.url,
    data: formData,
    type: "POST",
    ...
})
```

Comment: I'll give this a try tomorrow morning :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure If i got ur question well, But I think you are appending the form data to URL and using POST in ajax.

Can you try

$_REQUEST["whatever"] to see what you are getting

**EDIT**
After seeing the commnets I think I now got it

```
 function DoAjax( args )
{
    var formData =  $("form[name=" + args.formName + "]").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: args.url,
        data: {
            request: args.request,
        formData:formData
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            args.callback.html(data);
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            alert("error: " + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ".");
        }
    });

    return false;       
}
```

Now $_POST[formData] should work

**Edit**
see this as well

github.com/maxatwork/form2js

Comment: echo $_POST[ "formData" ] now gives me: ?username=wadawd&password=rgerg

Any chance you know how to get that into POST data in PHP?

Comment: Hi James,If you look more closely I have changed the url and data of your ajax call

Comment: Yea, I saw that... I've managed to output $_POST[ "formData" ] and get a serialized string returned... but short of splitting the string, is there a serialize function in php or something so that I can get it back into POST data or just an array?

Comment: You can use serailizeArray instead of serailize

Comment: You can also use the `parse_str` function from php

Comment: James , I guess I found something you would like :) see this https://github.com/maxatwork/form2js